# transfer javascript var created with 'passport' to express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

i created this `passportAuth.js` file fo authentication:

```
module.exports = function(passport, FacebookStrategy, config, mongoose, fbgraph){

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){ //make the user reference available threw multiple pages
    done(null,user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    userModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    })
})

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.fb.appID,
    clientSecret: config.fb.appSecret,
    callbackURL: config.fb.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'birthday', 'events', 'profileUrl', 'emails', 'likes']
}, function(accessToken, refershToken, profile, done){

    var fb = new fbgraph.Facebook(accessToken, 'v2.2');
    fb.me(function(err, me) {
        console.log(me);
    });
    fb.my.events(function(err, events) {
        console.log(events);
    });
    fb.my.friends(function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
    });

}))

}
```

until here every thing works ok and i am able to create the `fb` var with the data i want. the problem starts when i am trying to transfer this fb object to the express router inside my `routes.js` file. i want to render the data stored in this object into the `welcome.html` page but i cant figure out how to pass this var to the routes file and pass it to the render function.

this is how my routes file looks like:

```
module.exports = function(express, app, passport){
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
        res.render('index', {title: "welcome to aDating"});
    })

    function securePages(req, res, next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }

    router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_friends', 'public_profile', 'user_events' ] }));
        router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect:'/welcome', //if authentication is successful, navigate to this path
            failureRedirect:'/'         //else, navigate here
        }))

    router.get('/welcome', securePages, function(req, res, next){
        res.render('welcome', {title:'Welcome to aDating', user:req.user, ----PASS fb HERE--});
    })
}
```

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `passReqToCallback: true`, add something to the req object, and use it in a later middleware

Beware! This will clear after the request/response cycle ends! So e.g. if you set `req.tmpPassport` in a request to `/oauth/start`, and it redirects to facebook and back to `/oauth/end`, `req.tmpPassport` will be undefined again. If you need to keep track of something across redirects, use `req.session` instead.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true,
    clientID: config.fb.appID,
    clientSecret: config.fb.appSecret,
    callbackURL: config.fb.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'birthday', 'events', 'profileUrl', 'emails', 'likes']
}, function(req, accessToken, refershToken, profile, done){
    req.tmpPassport = {};
    var fb = new fbgraph.Facebook(accessToken, 'v2.2');
    fb.me(function(err, me) {
        req.tmpPassport.me = me;
    });
    fb.my.events(function(err, events) {
        req.tmpPassport.events = events;
    });
    fb.my.friends(function(err, result){
        req.tmpPassport.results = results;
    });

}))
```

Comment: thanks for answering Plato, one thing i couldn't figure out its ow to deal with the asynchronicity...routes gets empty object